# How to use openGL Widget?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt6

I want to put **OpenGL in a TabView Widget.**
I dragged the openGLWidget in the tabView UI and ran the code.
It is giving me the following error ->
error image:
[image: error image]

On clicking the path, It redirects me to ui_test.h file. -> ui_test.h file image:
[image: ui_test.h file image]

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eztKp_1kVJc and did the exact thing mentioned @ 06:25.

P.S: .pro file ->

```
QT       += core gui opengl
LIBS +=   -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt6 you must use `QT += openglwidgets` as indicated in [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglwidget.html).